# Installing QtCurve on 15.04 with KDE5

Tags: themes, dependencies, plasma-5, kde5

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 with KDE5. Now I really want to install a new theme: The Hex Kde theme.

Unfortunately there is no QtCurve option within System Settings.

I tried installing QtCurve with this command:

> sudo apt-get install QtCurve

Sadly enough I get this output:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    qtcurve : Depends: kwin-style-qtcurve but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is this solveable or am I unable to install QtCurve with KDE5 Plasma 5 desktop?

I found this bug report but I don't really know what it means:
[bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-style-qtcurve/+bug/1452218)

Kind regards,

Maarten

Answer (score 0):

You can install Debian packages. There are some dependence name don't match, but you can always correct them by your self.

Comment: I found more specific instruction https://plus.google.com/+DemitriusBelai/posts/KPUaJY7tu9e

Comment: and use version 1.8.18-3, not 1.8.18-3~b1, 'cause in that version dependencies are changed to previous versions.